# Can't move camera in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view

Noticed I wasn't able to pan with Alt + middle mouse button anymore, clicked numpad . like the tutorials online suggested and now I can't move or rotate either. I tried loading factory settings 5x times, didn't work. I went into File >> User Preferences to change the keys, didn't work. I'm at a lost here.

[Here's my blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/stux95fqo5egk05/LizardMan.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Do you mean SHIFT + middle button (not Alt) ? Your blend works fine on my computer.

Comment: Yeah Shift+MMB doesn't work either

Comment: There's no Edit mode for the camera. Are you talking about the Lock Camera To View option in the N panel > View options?